# Trying to compute cosine distance

Tags: python, dictionary, text-processing

I have some code here:

```
import math
from collections import Counter

def forSearch():

    words = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}}
    search = {'bit':1,'dog':3,'shoe':5}

    sizeFileVec = {}
    for term, innerDict in words.iteritems():
        for fileNum, appearances in innerDict.iteritems():
            if not sizeFileVec.has_key(fileNum):
                sizeFileVec[fileNum] = 0
            sizeFileVec[fileNum] += appearances ** 2
            for fileId in sizeFileVec:
                sizeFileVec[fileNum] = math.sqrt(sizeFileVec[fileNum])

    sizeSearchVec = 0
    for term, appearances in search.iteritems():
        sizeSearchVec += appearances ** 2
        sizeSearchVec = math.sqrt(sizeSearchVec)

    results = []
    for word, occurrences in search.iteritems():
        file_relevancy = Counter()
        for word, innerDict in words.iteritems():
            for fileNum, appear_in_file in innerDict.iteritems():
                file_relevancy[fileNum] += (occurrences * appear_in_file) / (sizeFileVec[fileNum] * sizeSearchVec)
        results = [fileNum for (fileNum, count) in file_relevancy.most_common(10)]
    return results


print forSearch()
```

words is a dictionary of {word:{fileNum:freq}} and search is {word:freq}

It is supposed to compute the cosine distance between each file and search so as to produce a list of most relevant files. However, it does not

The way the maths works is like so:

```
               bit     dog     shoe

File 1          3       3        0

File 2          4       0        0

File 3         19       4        0

File 4          0       5        0

Search          1       3        5
```

sim(1,S) = (3 * 1) + (3 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(3^2 + 3^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.478

sim(2,S) = (4 * 1) + (0 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(4^2 + 0^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.169

sim(3,S) = (19 * 1) + (4 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(19^2 + 4^2 +0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.26987

sim(4,S) = (0 * 1) + (5 * 3) + (0 * 5) / sqrt(0^2 + 5^2 + 0^2) * sqrt(1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2) = 0.507

Therefore [4,1,3,2] should be returned. However, at the moment [3,1,4,2] is being returned

Answer (score 1):

This this code instead:

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter

def forSearch():
    # Here it assumes that each key in search, is also in words. 
    words = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'shoe':{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}, 'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0}}
    search = {'bit':1,'dog':3,'shoe':5}
    num_files = 4 # TODO: , figure this out programatically



    # CALCULATE THE SIM(I,S), VALUES FOR I = 1 TO NUM_FILES
    file_relevancy = Counter()
    c = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in search.values()]))
    for i in range(1, num_files+1):
        words_ith_val = [words[x][i] for x in search.keys() ]
        a = sum([search[key] * words[key][i] for key in search.keys()])
        b = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in words_ith_val]))
        file_relevancy[i] = (a / (b * c))

    # RANK THE FILES AND RETURN
    return [x[0] for x in file_relevancy.most_common(num_files)]


print forSearch()
```

Comment: There is an error in ln 13. This code has a problem with words that are in the query but not in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version that should work even when the search terms are not contained in the words dictionary.

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter

def forSearch():
    words = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}, 'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0}}
    search = {'bit':1,'dog':3,'shoe':5}
    num_files = 4 # TODO: , figure this out programatically

    tempwords = dict(words)

    # HANDLE SEARCH ITEMS THAT ARE NOT IN THE WORDS DICTIONARY
    for key in search.keys():
        if not tempwords.has_key(key):
            tempwords[key] = {}
            for i in range(1, num_files+1):
                tempwords[key][i] = 0

    # CALCULATE THE SIM(I,S), VALUES FOR I = 1 TO NUM_FILES
    file_relevancy = Counter()
    c = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in search.values()]))
    for i in range(1, num_files+1):
        words_ith_val = [tempwords[x][i] for x in search.keys() ]
        a = sum([search[key] * tempwords[key][i] for key in search.keys()])
        b = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in words_ith_val]))
        file_relevancy[i] = (a / (b * c))

    # RANK THE FILES AND RETURN
    return [x[0] for x in file_relevancy.most_common(num_files)]


print forSearch()
```

Comment: This is great, I love you man I really do! One question though, The values calculated are different to the ones I did by hand? Did I do them wrong?

Comment: Also, why is i in range from 1 and not 0?

Comment: @DannyBoy  You can do a sanity check on the function by printing out the calculated values just before it does the return statement, eg:  print file_relevancy, which gives the values:   
4: 0.50709255283711, 1: 0.4780914437337575, 3: 0.2698714835958106, 2: 0.1690308509457033    The same as what you had calculated above.

Comment: @DannyBoy your files in the dictionary were keyed starting at number 1. So I did the loop in the range from 1 to num_files so that they would match up. If however your files were to start being indexed from 0, then by all means change the for loop to start from 0 as well.

Comment: @DannyBoy so... did this work for you? Or is there still issues with it?